# using per class boost::log::sources::logger from const member function

Tags: c++, boost, boost-logging

I want a log source per class like the basic_logger example from the [docs](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/sources.html#log.detailed.sources.basic_logger)

This works but I get a compiler error complaining about the constness when logging something from a const member function like so:

```
#include "boost/log/sources/channel_logger.hpp"
#include "boost/log/common.hpp"
#include "boost/log/utility/init/to_console.hpp"
#include "boost/log/utility/init/common_attributes.hpp"

class Test
{
    public:
        // this works, not a const function
        void test1()
        {
            BOOST_LOG(m_logger) << "Test 1";
        }

        // this will not compile, const function
        void test2() const            
        {
            BOOST_LOG(m_logger) << "Test 2";
        }
    private:
        boost::log::sources::channel_logger<std::string> m_logger;
};

int main()
{
    boost::log::add_common_attributes();
    boost::log::init_log_to_console();

    Test t;
    t.test1();
    t.test2();
    return 1;
}
```

In this example `Test::test2` gives a compile error because its const and `m_logger` is not. `Test::test1` works fine.

How can this be fixed in a clean way without `const_cast`, `mutable` etc.

Comment: As others have said, `mutable` IS the clean way to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the log is stored in the class, then of course you cannot modify it in a `const` context.

I realise that you asked for something else, but I honestly think that `mutable` is the appropriate solution here. This is exactly the use case that is why `mutable` exists.

Comment: Right, mutable **is** the clean way. This is exactly why it was added to the language.

Comment: @BoPersson: Yep. Avoiding it here seems daft.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the mutable logger outside of your class then all will work fine. Or you use something different which gives you an immutable logger object.